# AWS SDK and NODE JS --> UnknownEndpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have followed this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ec2-example-creating-an-instance.html

When I run the code below - I get the UnknowEndPoint error.

1. I have created an AWS IAM user and added the user to a group with the policy name "IAMFullAccess" - I don't know which other policy would fit (I can see in the AWS dashboard that my credentials has been used programmatically - So I guess this part works well...)?
2. I have placed my credentials in the .aws folder in a file named credentials.
3. I am not sure what actually to put inside the 'KeyName' below - currently I have entered the Key Pair Name I find by clicking on one of my existing AWS EC2 instances in the dashboard. Is this correct?

Is there some security group or similar I need to edit - to able to connect NodeJS to my AWS account? Otherwise I have no clue what to do?

In start.js file:

```
process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1;    
var AWS_SDK = require('./aws_sdk');
var aws_sdk = new AWS_SDK();

aws_sdk.CopyInstance();
```

In aws_sdk.js file:

```
function AWS_SDK() {

    this.CopyInstance = function() {

        try {

            // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

            //Set the region
            AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2a'});

            var instanceParams = {
                ImageId: 'ami-0...',
                InstanceType: 't1.micro',
                KeyName: '<Key_name>',
                MinCount: 1,
                MaxCount: 1
            };

            // Create a promise on an EC2 service object
            var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();

            // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
            instancePromise.then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                    console.log("Created instance", instanceId);
                    // Add tags to the instance
                    var tagParams = {
                        Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
                            {
                                Key: 'Name',
                                Value: 'SDK Sample'
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    // Create a promise on an EC2 service object
                    var tagPromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).createTags(tagParams).promise();
                    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
                    tagPromise.then(
                        function (data) {
                            console.log("Instance tagged");
                        }).catch(
                        function (err) {
                            console.error(err, err.stack);
                        });
                }).catch(
                function (err) {
                    console.error(err, err.stack);
                });
        }
        catch(e){
            wl.info('Error: ' + e);
        }
    } 

function create() {

    if(globalAWS === null)
        globalAWS = new AWS_SDK();

    return globalAWS;
}

module.exports = create;
```

ERROR:

> { UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com'.
>   This service may not be available in the`us-east-2a' region.
>       at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:486:46)
>       at Request.callListeners (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
>       at Request.emit (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
>       at Request.emit (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
>       at ClientRequest.error (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:325:22)
>       at ClientRequest. (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:93:19)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)   message:    'Inaccessible host: `ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be
>   available in the`us-east-2a\' region.',   code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
>   region: 'us-east-2a',   hostname: 'ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com',
>   retryable: true,   originalError:    { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com:443
>          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
>        message:
>         'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com:443',
>        errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>        code: 'NetworkingError',
>        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>        hostname: 'ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com',
>        host: 'ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com',
>        port: 443,
>        region: 'us-east-2a',
>        retryable: true,
>        time: 2019-01-14T20:03:42.177Z },   time: 2019-01-14T20:03:42.177Z } 'UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host:
>   `ec2.us-east-2a.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be available in
>   the`us-east-2a\' region.\n    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:486:46)\n
>   at Request.callListeners
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n
>   at Request.emit
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n
>   at Request.emit
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)\n
>   at ClientRequest.error
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:325:22)\n
>   at ClientRequest.
>   (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:93:19)\n
>   at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at
>   ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)\n    at
>   TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)\n    at
>   TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

If I change the REGION to "us-east-2" (delete the 'a' at the end) the error changes to this:

```
{ Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    at Request.extractError (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\ec2.js:50:35)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Workspace\BitBucket\Test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message:
   'The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.',
  code: 'Unsupported',
  time: 2019-01-14T20:31:55.954Z,
  requestId: '815a44e2-5d0d-453e-a4ff-6faac2695064',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 51.269952198296934 } 'Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.\n    at Request.extractError (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\services\\ec2.js:50:35)\n    at Request.callListeners (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\request.js:683:14)\n    at Request.transition (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\request.js:685:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (D:\\Workspace\\BitBucket\\Test\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\sequential_executor.js:116:18)'
```

Update 1:

I changed the REGION from to 'us-est-2' and now also updated my ~/.aws/config file (before the file only contained 1 line/row: 'region=us-west-2'):

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json
```

Now I get this error (when I try to decode it in the CMD) - I still don't understand what extra roles I have to give/grant my IAM-AWS user to be able read the error message?

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DecodeAuthorizationMessage operation: User: arn:aws:iam::0046xxxxxxx:user/user_name is not authorized to perform: sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage
```

Comment: The doc for runInstances explains that KeyName is "The name of the key pair."

Comment: Thank you - Then it should be correct :)

Comment: I suspect the 'Unsupported' error is because the instance type you are launching is not available in that region/AZ. Note that the t1.micro is a previous generation instance and it has been replaced by t2.micro, so please use that.

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your AWS region as `us-east-2a`. That isn't a region, that is an availability zone. Your region should be configured as `us-east-2`.

Comment: Thank you. But then I get the second error message instead? What it is which it doesn't support?

Answer (score 0):

After I added the IAM role: "AdministratorAccess" all issues were gone :) The question is now - which role(s) are actually needed to be granted for it to work..."AdministratorAccess" was just for testing purpose.